# XPath and Java, expression works in chorme console but not in java

Tags: java, xpath

I am using Java 17 & JavaFX 17. I am trying to extract information from a web page and I use a WebView to get my document (I know this works well and I can use Document class methods successfully to search for nodes). I am now trying to move to XPath.

I first exercised in Chrome's console and successfully used the expression *"//div[@class='pagerCurrentText']"* to get the nodes I want but when I switched to java it returned none (I double-checked for typos etc.).

Here is the relevant java code I use:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

var nodes = (NodeList) xPath
    .compile( "//div[@class='pagerCurrentText']" )
    .evaluate( document, XPathConstants.NODESET );
```

While investigating, I noticed that the expression *"//*[@class='pagerCurrentText']"* was working as I expected in Chome's console but surprisingly in java as well indicating the problem is probably not related to XPath itself.

Has anyone an idea why the expression with div does not work in java while the other does?

Comment: Java might use an HTML parser like the browser and follow the conventions to put any HTML elements into the XHTML namespace but while XPath in the browser with JavaScript is hacked/patched (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#interactions-with-xpath-and-xslt) to assume that namespace for unqualified names like `div` the DOM Java API don't do you that favour but look for `div` elements in no namespace and can't find any as the `div` elements are in the XHTML namespace. A workaround: switch to XPath processing using Saxon 9 or 10 and XPath 2 or 3 where you can set a default element namespace.

Comment: I support the stated theories. The code you show is looking good, and what you did not show but is of importance is the XML document and the node's namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment, the HTML5 based parsing puts HTML elements in the DOM in the XHTML namespace but then HTML5 goes on to patch/hack namespace resolution for XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#interactions-with-xpath-and-xslt.

The standard XPath 1.0 based implementations in the Java world, however, don't adapt to HTML5 conventions.

XPath 2 and 3, as implemented in the Java world by Saxon 9 or 10, allow you to set a default element namespace (like the XHTML namespace) for XPath evaluation.

You can switch from the JRE/JDK XPath 1.0 based implementation to XPath 2 and 3 with Saxon 9 or 10 HE. There you have an option to set up a default element namespace. In general, it is recommended to switch to Saxon's API, as it is more convenient to use the full power of the XPath 3.1 language and type system than trying to use it with the JAXP XPath 1.0 API; however, a quick shot would be to add a dependency to Saxon 10.6 HE and then use

```
XPath xPath = new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl().newXPath();

((XPathEvaluator)xPath).getStaticContext().setDefaultElementNamespace("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

var nodes = (NodeList) xPath
    .compile( "//div[@class='pagerCurrentText']" )
    .evaluate( document, XPathConstants.NODESET );
```

That way the `div` elements are looked for in the XHTML namespace the WebKit browser engine has put them in while you don't need to qualify the name with a namespace prefix as you would have to do with a standard XPath 1.0 implementation.